# jQuery Each function class toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to remove a class for all elements of each() function.

Right now when I click on a .btn element it adds "selected" class to it, again click on .btn it removes that "selected" class.

But when I click other .btn element it should remove "selected" class from previous .btn elements.

```js
$('.btn').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.selected { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lorem" class="btn">Lorem</div>
<div id="ipsum" class="btn">Ipsum</div>
<div id="dolor" class="btn">Doloe</div>
<div id="Set" class="btn">Set</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've over complicated this a little. Firstly you don't need an `each()` loop as the `click()` will be applied to a collection of elements if you provide them in the selector. Secondly you can use `toggleClass()` on the element which is clicked. Then you can use `removeClass()` on all the other `.btn` elements to remove the class. Try this:

```js
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  $btns.not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lorem" class="btn">Lorem</div>
<div id="ipsum" class="btn">Ipsum</div>
<div id="dolor" class="btn">Doloe</div>
<div id="Set" class="btn">Set</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need each nor else; toggleClass and remove from siblings will work

```js
$('.btn').on("click",function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
})
```

```css
.selected { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lorem" class="btn">Lorem</div>
<div id="ipsum" class="btn">Ipsum</div>
<div id="dolor" class="btn">Doloe</div>
<div id="Set" class="btn">Set</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your existing code, remove all classes from all buttons in the `else`:

```js
$('.btn').each(function() {
  $(this).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
      $(this).removeClass("selected");
    } else {
      $('.btn').removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lorem" class="btn">Lorem</div>
<div id="ipsum" class="btn">Ipsum</div>
<div id="dolor" class="btn">Doloe</div>
<div id="Set" class="btn">Set</div>
```